# Getting friend_count with fql -facebook C# sdk

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a windows phone 7 application with facebook and the C# sdk for getting information from facebook friends. I am stuck somewhere...

I can get a friend count in a foreach loop with this, but when I call that function from another function it returns 0. Why?

```
    private object GetFriendsCount() {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
        var query = string.Format("SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid={0}", "me()");
        // var query1 = string.Format("SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1={0})", "me()");
        fb.GetAsync("fql", new { q = query });
        object returnVal = 0;
        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            var data = (IList<object>)result["data"];
            foreach (var comment in data.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>())
            {
                returnVal = comment["friend_count"];
               // Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(returnVal.ToString()));
            }

        };

        return returnVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT friend_count, name FROM user WHERE uid = me()`

should give you what you are looking for.  in my experience if you are wanting to aggregate data however, a loop is best.  The `friend_count` column will give you a total number, but also includes inactive, disabled, or abandoned accounts.

Comment: i can get the friend_count in foreach loop but the problem is i cant return it from function, it always returns 0 after called return returnVal;

Comment: the problem is solved by me, thanks anyway. 

here is the code, maybe it helps to others: [link](http://pastebin.com/BSUmB0ch)